# Creating project documentation for java web project in gh-pages

Tags: git, jekyll, github-pages

I have a maven based java web project with source code in master branch. I want to create documentation for that project using jekyll, and commit the documentation along with the source in docs folder.

So, I initialized a new jekyll site named docs in my root of my project

```
 $ jekyll new docs
```

Now I have a docs folder within my project root, from where I can generate and serve the documentation.

```
 $ cd docs
 $ jekyll build
```

All that is good and I have docs/_site folder with the generated HTML in it. **How can I push this generated HTML to gh-pages branch** ? 
Does, github provide anyway to do that? Any ideas/suggestions/best practices re:this?

## EDIT

The main problem is that my jekyll code is in **master** and not in **gh-pages branch**. From the documentation at github I understand that I need to push the jekyll site to gh-pages directory.

Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: David, I wish TFM was more descriptive. If you can help ... great ... otherwise thank you for trying to answer.

Comment: Did you have a repository url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to get your generated pages over to your `gh-pages` branch. One way of doing that would be to copy `docs/_site` to temporary location, then switch to `gh-pages` and copy the files over there:

```
$ cp -R docs/_site /tmp/      # Copy web page files to temporary location
$ git checkout gh-pages       # Checkout gh-pages branch
$ git rm -rf .                # Delete existing files
$ mv /tmp/_site/* .           # Move web page files to repo
$ git add -A                  # Add new files
$ git commit                  # Commit new files
$ git push origin gh-pages    # Push changes back to GitHub
```

Comment: I was looking for a more straightforward way to solve this problem, but it seems that your solution is the best bet for now. Thank you!